# JavaScript all possible characters after string

Tags: javascript, php

I'm writing a script for a website I'm currently building.

```
    var ownerForm = $('#item_owner_form_');
    ownerForm.submit(function(ev) {
        //$.ajax({
            //'url': 'checklist_changeowner.php',
            //'type': 'GET',
            //'dataType': 'json',
            //'data': {owner: blabla, item: blablbalba, checklist: blabla},
            //'success': function() {
            //  
            //}
        //});

        alert(ownerForm.serialize());
        ev.preventDefault();
    });
```

As you've probably already seen, I've set a fixed id for the ownerform (in this case #item_owner_form_) However, I am creating lots of forms through PHP and this is not what I'm looking for. For example, a form that will be generated could be identified as #item_owner_form_42 or as #item_owner_form_913.

Is there a universal character to make sure the ownerForm variable will use all of the forms that start with #item_owner_form_ ? Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: But you can do the same using `class`, can't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `class` for that. It can be common for many(similar) elements.

So, your all forms would look like this,

```
<form id="item_owner_form_1" class="commonItemForm">
</form>

<form id="item_owner_form_2" class="commonItemForm">
</form>
```

And use the class in jQuery like this,

```
    $('.commonItemForm').submit(function(ev) {
        alert($(this).serialize());
        ev.preventDefault();
        // This function will get triggered for every form which has commonItemForm class.
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much but when I serialize the form now it serializes the results of every form on the page and I receive a huge string. That's why I was using IDs. Do you have another idea for me on how to fix this?